# Use ratio test to find value of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(\frac{1}{10})^{k+1}}{k(k+1)}$

Tags: summation

I know the series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(\frac{1}{10})^{k+1}}{k(k+1)}$$ is equal to $$\frac{1}{10}-\frac{9}{10}\ln \Big(\frac{10}{9}\Big)$$ but how would I use the ratio test to show this is true?

I also know that: 
$$
(1-x)\ln(1-x)=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{x^{k+1}}{k}-\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{x^k}{k}
=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^{k+1}}{k(k+1)}$$

Comment: The **ratio test** does not find the value of a series.  It finds only whether the series converges or not.

Comment: I was told that it would work. What test should I use to show this converges to that value?

Comment: Use your last line, and find what to plug in for $x$ to get your series.  But I would not call it a "test".

Comment: Okay, thank you.